# How do I print a rectangle with increasing value of i

Tags: python, for-loop, while-loop, range

I have been trying to print a rectangle where the width and height are user inputs, this should be the output for a rectangle of 3x5

```
0 1 2 3 4

5 6 7 8 9

10 11 12 13 14
```

Do you have any ideas to keep my value of i in the for loop keep increasing instead of restarting with each string?

This is what I have tried:

```
width = eval(input('Please enter the width of the rectangle: '))
height = eval(input('Please enter the height of the rectangle:'))

for i in range(height):
    print(''.join([str(j) for j in range(0,width)]))
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use `i` and `width` to add an offset to each row's values, with a slight modification to your current code:

```
width = eval(input('Please enter the width of the rectangle: '))
height = eval(input('Please enter the height of the rectangle: '))

for i in range(height):
    print(' '.join([str(j + i * width) for j in range(0,width)]))
```

Note that if your input consists of just integers and not expressions, you could also use `int` to cast the input string to an integer:

```
width = int(input('Please enter the width of the rectangle: '))
height = int(input('Please enter the height of the rectangle:'))
```

Comment: You should change the eval() to int(), otherwise good answer

Comment: You're right, but this still works correctly, and I wouldn't change it because it's not what the question is about. Although I doubt it, but the OP might have a reason to use eval(), e.g. to allow expressions (such as '2+2') to be passed as input and calculate the width/height from that expression.

Comment: Thank you very much Adam, this indeed worked, and you Chris are both right I do not believe that is necessary to allow expressions such as: 2+2 . I have changed the eval() to int(). Thank you guys!

Answer (score 1):

Nice question. This is what I would do. Capture the width and height like you did:

```
width= int(input('Please enter the width of the rectangle: '))

height=int(input('Please enter the height of the rectangle:'))
```

Then create an empty string.

```
outputString= ""
```

Now just use a for loop to add to that string

```
count = 0
for c in range(height):
   for r in range(width):
      count+=1
      outputString+=" "+str(count)
   outputString+="\n"
```

Basically you add a new number each time, then after you finish each row you append a new line to the string. Then you simply print outputString.

Please accept the answer if it works. If not please comment below, and we can help!

Comment: This almost works. But you need to cast "count" to a string to be able to concatenate it. Also, I would avoid using emptyString as a variable name. How long is it going to be empty? Maybe something like outputString :)

Comment: haha ya ill edit the name to outputString. Also you are correct about casting the string, my bad lol

Answer (score 0):

I would do this :

```
width= eval(input('Please enter the width of the rectangle: '))

height=eval(input('Please enter the height of the rectangle:'))

i=0
for j in range(height*width):
    if (i+1)%width==0:
        print(i)
    else:
        print(i, end=" ")
    i+=1
```

It's not very compact but it does the job.

Comment: Thank you Vynokris, the code works just fine and it is pretty straightforward. Thank you for your contribution!